# Pre filled form data using id in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

Actually Everything is working fine and Id is also coming in URL but Data is not coming in fields when I click on Update button
Here is my Code

This is models that I have created

```
#Models.py
from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.IntegerField()
    cnic = models.CharField(max_length = 13)
    blood_group = models.CharField(max_length= 10)
    last_donation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This is MY views

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import UserForm
from django.urls import reverse



def home(request):
    data = User.objects.all()  #This function display All data on homePage
    context = {
        'data': data
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html',context)
    
def donor(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        userform = UserForm(request.POST)   #This Add New User
        if userform.is_valid():
            userform.save()
    else:
        userform = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'donor.html',{'userform':userform,})

def Update(request,pk):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        p_id = User.objects.get(pk = pk)
        form = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance= p_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('home'))
    context['form'] = UserForm()
    return render(request, 'update.html',context)
```

This is my URLS

```
#urls.py

from django.urls import  path
from blood import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.home, name='home'),
    path('donor/', views.donor, name = 'donor'),
    path('update/<int:pk>', views.Update, name='update'),
]
```

This is Forms that I have created and check validation

```
#forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import  User
from datetime import  timedelta
from django.utils.timezone import datetime
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "__all__"
    

    def clean_cnic(self):
        cnic = self.cleaned_data['cnic']
        if not User.objects.filter(cnic=cnic).exists():
            return cnic 
        try:
            u_obj = User.objects.get(cnic = cnic)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            raise ValidationError("User Does not exist")
        if u_obj:
            previous_date = u_obj.last_donation
            current_date = datetime.now().astimezone()
            final = current_date - previous_date
            print(final)
            if final < timedelta(days = 90):
                raise ValidationError("U have to wait 90 days to complete")  
            return cnic 


    def clean_blood_group(self):
        cnic = self.cleaned_data.get("cnic")
        blood_group = self.cleaned_data['blood_group']
        if not User.objects.filter(cnic = cnic).exists():
            return blood_group
        obj = User.objects.get(cnic = cnic)
        if obj.blood_group == blood_group:
            return blood_group    
        raise ValidationError("Blood group does not match")
```

This is HTML code that works with Update function

```
#update.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %}
  update      
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
<div class = 'container mt-5 pt-6'>
  <div class = 'col-md-5 mx-auto'> 
    <h3>This is update Page</h3>
      <form method = "POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.non_field_errors }}
          <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.cnic.errors }}
              <label  class="form-label">Enter CNIC</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "cnic" >
              {{cnic}}
          </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name = 'first_name'>
                {{first_name}}
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label  class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "last_name" >
                {{last_name}}
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "mobile_number" >
                  {{mobile_number}}
                </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                {{ form.blood_group.errors}}
                  <label  class="form-label">Blood Group</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "blood_group">
                  {{blood_group}}
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="update">Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Everything is working fine. No Error is coming but not work properly. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Better way to update a form is adding a form initial to hold the field data that needs to be updated. Also you had called your form object ( context['form'] = UserForm()) on  the form context  variable that kinda made it not to save the data

```
def Update(request,pk):
    context = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        p_id = User.objects.get(pk = pk)
        form = UserForm(request.POST or None, instance=p_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        form = UserForm(
                initial={
                  'cnic':p_id.cnic
                 'first_name':p_di.first_name,
                 'last_name' :p_id.lasr_name,
                  'mobile_number':p_di.mobile_number,
                   'blood_group': p_di.blood_group,})

    context['form'] = form 
    return render(request, 'update.html',context)
```

Here is now to how that data in your form edit update

```
#update.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}


{% block title %}
  update      
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
<div class = 'container mt-5 pt-6'>
  <div class = 'col-md-5 mx-auto'> 
    <h3>This is update Page</h3>
      <form method = "POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.non_field_errors }}
          <div class="mb-3">
            {{ form.cnic.errors }}
              <label  class="form-label">Enter CNIC</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "cnic" value="{{form.initial.cnic}}">
          </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name = 'first_name' value="{{form.initial.first_name}}">
                
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                <label  class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "last_name" value="{{form.initial.last_name}}" >
                
              </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                  <label class="form-label">Mobile Number</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name = "mobile_number" value="{{form.initial.mobile_number}}" >
                </div>
              <div class="mb-3">
                {{ form.blood_group.errors}}
                  <label  class="form-label">Blood Group</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name ="blood_group" value="{{form.initial.blood_group}}">
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="update">Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```